# R package build failed when checking examples

Tags: r, compilation, package

I am building my R package. However, when compiling it using CMD, the build fails because of the examples. I show you my function header for clarity:

```
#' @param data a dataframe containing the data to be modelled  
#' @param string identifying the location  
#' @param parameters a dataframe where the parameters for all the functions   
needed are saved  
#' @param period string saying whether the horizon to model  
#'  
#' @import dplyr  
#'  
#' @return list  
#' @export  
#' @examples   
Runner(data=data,Site="ABC",parameters=parameter,period="6-month")

Runner <- function(data, 
Site="ABC",parameters=parameter,period="6-month"){

  if(!is.data.frame(data)){
    stop("data must be a data.frame")
  }
```

and so on. I have only included the first test because it seems to be the following error message seems to refer to it.

When compiling, I get the following error message:

> Running examples in ‘SiteRunner.R’ failed
>     The error most likely occurred in:
>
> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
>
> #### Name: Runner
>
> #### Title: Feature engineer and Model the chosen location
>
> #### Aliases: Runner
>
> #### ** Examples
>
> Runner(data=data,Site="ABC",parameters=parameter,period="6-month")
>     Error in Runner(data = data, Site = "ABC", parameters = parameter,  : 
>       data must be a data.frame
>     Execution halted

Any help? I see it often is the case that `@export` is missing, but it is not my case.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I don't see a definition of `data` in the examples.

Comment: unless `data` is an object exported in your package, then it will be interpreted as a function, which will cause your example to fail. You should define data in your example

Comment: To add to the comment of Aaron, it's always better not to name a variable with the same name as R's functions. This will always creates further complications than necessary.

Comment: @snair1591 I actually find these complications extremely rare, not an "always" thing. I would wager that 99.9% of the questions on SO that use `data` or `df` as data frame names created no complications. Variables need to be defined, whether or not the name is being re-used.

Comment: @Aaron Hayman thank you, that solved it

Comment: @snair1591 using the name for a variable will seldom cause trouble, since it R can generally tell when a function is being used as a function and will look for a function and the default functions will remain on the search path. I ran into trouble once though with a function that I built after someone loaded a library which had its own `range` function. I had to modify my function to use `base::range`