# CRAN checks errors on roxygen @examples: base::assign and missing reshape2

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I am trying to push the following package to CRAN, but I keep getting an error on the check.

Error:

```
✓  checking R/sysdata.rda ...
    WARNING
   ‘qpdf’ is needed for checks on size reduction of PDFs
✓  checking installed files from ‘inst/doc’ ...
✓  checking files in ‘vignettes’ ...
E  checking examples (3s)
   Running examples in ‘oRus-Ex.R’ failed
   The error most likely occurred in:
   
   > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
   > ### Name: analyseStories
   > ### Title: Analysing Stories
   > ### Aliases: analyseStories
   > 
   > ### ** Examples
   > 
   > # Transform the stories
   > fileUrl <- example_stories()
   > stories <- analyseStories(fileUrl, 7)
   Joining, by = "word"
   Joining, by = "word"
   Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘reshape2’
   Calls: analyseStories ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
   Execution halted
```

Current problems:

- The example is in `orus::analyseStores(...)` function.
- The example actually runs and works on the `pkgdown` website.
- The error appears only when doing `devtools::check`

I have tried multiple things:

- This answer [base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv") ERROR when using devtools::check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117334/baseassign-ptime-proc-time-pos-checkexenv-error-when-using-devtool) suggested using `dontrun{...}`. It passes CRAN's check, but it was bounced by a person after a couple of days.
- This answer [R package fails devtools::check, because "could not find function" even though the function is imported in NAMESPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509068/r-package-fails-devtoolscheck-because-could-not-find-function-even-though-t) suggested doing `require` on the missing library. I did `require(reshape2)` but the check still does not pass.
- This answer ["Could not find function" in Roxygen examples during CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722297/could-not-find-function-in-roxygen-examples-during-cmd-check) suggests that I need to make all my functions public (exported). I don't want to do that. I tried doing `orus:::some_function(...)` to call to the non-exported functions inside `analyseStores` but it doesn't work either.
- According to this one: [R package build failed when checking examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181847/r-package-build-failed-when-checking-examples) the data is working and the function has the `@export` tag. Also, namespace is properly updated.

I have run out of options. Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Why was it bounced by a person?

Comment: Every user should be able to run the examples without error, but you are loading a package they might not have. You'd need a `dontrun`.

Comment: @Axeman after the automated check, a person checks the package. And they bounced it back because I had used `\dontrun{...}` on the example that refuses to work.

Comment: @Axeman The problem is I am not using any `reshape2` function directly. It is all due to transitive dependencies. If I put `reshape2` on the Imports in Description file, I get a warning that the package is not needed D:

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you need to load `reshape2` for that example.

Comment: It sounds to me that the example that you can't run is just a symptom, but not the root of the issue here. But rather, you have a deeper issue with dependencies not working as they should.

Comment: Try adding `reshape2` to Suggests. I had similar issue today when using `sjlabelled::read_spss` in my package. When checking via ´devtools::check` both in my examples and my tests I got an error that `haven` is needed for this function. After adding `haven` to Suggests both the examples and the tests passed.

Comment: In relation to the \dontrun getting bounced back ; can you also add a `require` statement i.e. `\dontrun{
if (require("reshape2")) {
  your_example}}` . This is seen pretty regularly in help files.

Comment: @stefan Ended up adding `reshape2` to suggests using `usethis::usepackage("reshape2", "Suggests")`. For now, CRAN check passes and I've submitted to CRAN. Hoping it doesn't get bounced back. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @stefan suggested in the comments, I had to add `reshape2` into the Suggested packages in the description file. I added using:

`usethis::usepackage("reshape2", "Suggests")`

Followed by regenerating the docs:

`devtools:document()`

Package is on its way to CRAN!